# Simulating an anchor point when translating in Core Gaphics

Tags: iphone, macos, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

Core Graphics does not provide an anchor point property, and all transforming/translating assumes an anchor point 0,0 (lower left). Core Animation, does provide an anchor point, but we are not using CA.

Does anyone know how to modify a transformation matrix (used with CGAffineTransform) so that we can simulate different anchor point locations (e.g. bottom middle, center, etc)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Translate the desired point to 0, 0. Then apply whatever transformation you want. Then apply the inverse translation.

Say you want to rotate about the point 25, 25. Do this:

```
CGAffineTransform *t = CGAffineTransformMake();
t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t, -25, -25);
t = CGAffineTransformRotate(t, angle);
t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t, 25, 25);
```

At this point, t is a transform which will rotate by angle about 25, 25.